# Local database of application will be same on updated version of application

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, versioning, local-database

I have one application in app store. It has local database where user stores some information. Now I am planning to release the second version of the application. My question is, will the data enter by user in the first version of application will be available in the second version of it or will it be blank.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to test for the previous version in code and merge them programmatically.

Something like this:

```
- (void)merge {
    NSString *dataDir = Doogie(@"data");
    NSString *sqlDir  = Doogie(@"sql");
    NSString *dataPath = PathAppend(dataDir, @"name.db");
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
        ILogPlus(@"%@", @"No merge necessary");
        return;
    }
    const char *oldDBPath = [dataPath UTF8String];
    const char *mainDBPath = [PathAppend(sqlDir, @"name.db") UTF8String];
    sqlite3 *mainDB;
    if (sqlite3_open(mainDBPath, &mainDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *attachSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ATTACH DATABASE \'%s\' AS old_db", oldDBPath];
        char *errorMessage;
        if (sqlite3_exec(mainDB, [attachSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMessage) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt;

            NSString *selectSQL = @"insert into main.favorites select * from old_db.favorites";
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(mainDB, [selectSQL UTF8String] , -1, &selectStmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
                while (sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error while creating select statement: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(mainDB));
            }

            selectSQL = @"insert into main.meals select * from old_db.meals";
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(mainDB, [selectSQL UTF8String] , -1, &selectStmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
                while (sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error while creating select statement: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(mainDB));
            }

            selectSQL = @"insert or ignore into main.usda select * from old_db.usda";
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(mainDB, [selectSQL UTF8String] , -1, &selectStmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
                while (sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error while creating select statement: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(mainDB));
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error while attaching databases: '%s'", errorMessage);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database at %@ with error %s", mainDBPath, sqlite3_errmsg(mainDB));
        sqlite3_close(mainDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment... :)

Comment: @Satish, you're welcome. If it answered your question, please select it as the answer.

Comment: ya i will once i implement it.. I still couldn't find any way to detect the version of the application if you would let me know that part also then it would be great. Thanks...

Comment: NSString * version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

Comment: Thanks for comment.. I have done one exercise one thing in which i installed the application and then entered value in the database of it. and then i changed the version of the app and installed it again it didn't change the the value i have entered in the previous version of app.. does that mean it automatically keeps the local database of previous version app. i didn't did any coping the database of old version to to new i just checked the condition of database existence..

Comment: Yes it keeps everything in the user's documents folder during an update